# PHP advanced graphics library

Tags: php, graphics, filter

I'm developing a graphic manipulation web service in PHP, I want to accept images, apply filters and output them instantly. Is there any library out there to accomplish this task?

(think of filters like the ones used in this app http://www.toon-fx.com/toonpaint/)

Comment: Maybe you should look into Flash? Server-side processing doesn't work well with this sort of functionality.

Comment: Or maybe have a look at the recent JavaScript Canvas libraries

Answer (score 3):

this link contains examples how to create and apply filters. It uses GD library.
[How To Create and Apply Image Filters in PHP](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/37179/1954)

Comment: Great link! I've added it to my Favorites folder for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting Gordon's comment, you should check out PaintbrushJS.

http://mezzoblue.github.com/PaintbrushJS/demo/